# How do I access my app code from my tests in a Swift project?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, testing

I have an Swift Xcode project with code such as:

```
class Utils: NSObject {
    class func cleanString (input: String, trim: Bool) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then I try to test it:

```
import XCTest

class AppTests: XCTestCase {
    func testConfiguratio() {
        Utils.cleanString("foo", trim: true)
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
/Users/pupeno/Projects/macninja/AppTests/AppTests.swift:35:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'Utils'
```

I have Host Application APIs enabled:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Be sure that `Utils` class checkbox is selected also for Tests, a.e. Target Memebership

Answer (score 2):

If this is an OSX project - make sure you included

```
@Testable import YOURPROJECTNAME
```

Above the 'class AppTests: XCTestCase'
and clean your project files.

[My Previous question where I had a similar issue is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620434/unable-to-access-main-target-methods-when-adding-tests-to-osx-project-in-swift/38623557#38623557)

Hope this helps ( even a year later...)

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said already, the library code and the test code are 2 different modules. So you have to import the library into the test code and also make the functions that you want to test public, e.g:

```
public class Utils: NSObject {
    public class func cleanString (input: String, trim: Bool) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
import XCTest
import Utils

class AppTests: XCTestCase {
    func testConfiguratio() {
        Utils.cleanString("foo", trim: true)
    }
}
```

If you want to see working code look at [my IBANtools library project](https://github.com/mike-lischke/IBANTools) which implements exactly this scenario (class functions, swift framework, lots of testing).

Comment: A lot has changed, but this answer still holds _mostly_ true.  You can now import your module with '@testable import ModuleName' in the test file and remove the 'public' keyword from the class definition you are testing (if it was only added for testability)

Answer (score 0):

The module that contains your tests is distinct from the module that contains your app code. When you want to access classes that are contained within a separate module you need to ensure that the to-be-imported classes are marked as `public`:

```
public class Utils: NSObject {
    class func cleanString (input: String, trim: Bool) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}
```