# Unable to access Main Target Methods when Adding Tests to OSX Project in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xctest

I have tried adding a testing bundle to my Project which seems to have succeeded.

However when I try to create instances of the Classes in my main project- I am unable to see them.

The Project seems to build fine - but I can' instantiate any of the test objects

Any ideas how to access them

Example Class to Test:

```
class EmailHelper: NSObject {
    func generateEmailBody (greeting: String, bodyContent: String) -> String {
        //Content goes in here
return message
    }
}

import XCTest

class MyProject_DesktopTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
    // The Test would go in here but I can't seem to resolve EmailHelper class- it generates a lint error
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        self.measureBlock {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating your classes? Please include that code here.

Comment: The answers on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192778/how-do-i-access-my-app-code-from-my-tests-in-a-swift-project/29193159#29193159) may help.

Comment: I added an example class to  test to the question above.    I tried adding @testable Import MyProjectName before the class - but it doesn't seem to be able to detect my Main Target so its still not working.

Comment: Wierd - I cleared my Project files and suddently it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding Testable to the top of the class( This appears to be OSX specific issue)

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyProjectName // <--- This was the missing bit.... :)
class MyProject_DesktopTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
    // The Test would go in here but I can't seem to resolve EmailHelper class- it generates a lint error
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        self.measureBlock {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

Also be sure to clean your project after adding it an it seems to work.